# Have they solved this exercise correct?(banach space, function space).

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

Please look at this exercise:
It is the last question I have a problem with

[image: Banach space of continuous functions]

Here is the solution:

[image: Solution]

They say that $\|I(1)\|=\sup|g(t)|$. But isn't $\|I(1)\|=\int_0^1g(t)dt$? If so, what is the correct answer?

Comment: Do you realize that it's difficult to read the images?

Comment: @user21820 I understand, I have no problem reading it, I really don't understand why it may be viewed differently for you. Here are the links directly to the images:, can you see them clear here: ? image 1: http://s27.postimg.org/y8d4c57wz/image.png , image 2: http://s1.postimg.org/am6ii8anz/image.png

Comment: @user119615: The image is too small to read even in the link. Can you somehow made it bigger?

Comment: @John Does it work if you open them as .jpg? Try these links: http://s27.postimg.org/y8d4c57wz/image.jpg   and http://s1.postimg.org/am6ii8anz/image.jpg , if that works maybe it is a problem with the .png images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Since $g(t) \geq 0$, it follows that $I(1)$ is a non-decreasing function on $[0,1]$, and hence, $||I(1)|| = (I(1))(1) =\int_0^1 g(t) dt$. In fact, one can use the estimate
$$ \int_{0}^1 |f(t)g(t)|\, dt \leq \int_0^1 \left(\sup|f(t)|\right)|g(t)|\, dt = ||f||\int_0^1 |g(t)|\, dt $$
to show that one can take $M = \int_0^1 |g(t)|\, dt$ for all $g \in C$, which is better than $M = \sup |g(t)|$.

Comment: Thanks, and it is also the fact that $\int_0^1g(t)dt$, is the least of all possible M's you can chose, making that the operator-norm?

Comment: Yes. For $g$ positive, we have $\int_0^1 g(t)\, dt = ||I(1)|| \leq ||I||\cdot||1|| = ||I||$. On the other hand, the inequality in my answer shows that for all $g \in C$, we have $||I|| \leq \int_0^1 |g(t)|\,dt$.